# Proof That $\sin{(bt)} = b\sin{(t)}$?

Tags: solution-verification, taylor-expansion, fake-proofs, trigonometric-series

Note the Taylor expansion for $\sin{x}$:
$$
  \sin{x} = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \cdots
$$

Now consider the Taylor expansion for $\sin(bt)$:
$$
\begin{align}
  \sin{(bt)} &= (bt) - \frac{(bt)^3}{3!} + \frac{(bt)^5}{5!} - \frac{(bt)^7}{7!} + \cdots \\
  &= b\left[b^0t - \frac{b^2t^3}{3!} + \frac{b^4t^5}{5!} - \frac{b^6t^7}{7!} + \cdots\right]
\end{align}
$$

This is where it gets interesting; define $c^{m+1}\equiv b^m$ and substitute it for $b$ in the brackets,
$$
\begin{align}
  \sin{(bt)} &= b\left[ct - \frac{c^3t^3}{3!} + \frac{c^5t^5}{5!} - \frac{c^7t^7}{7!} + \cdots\right] \\
  &= b\sin{(c^1 t)} \\
  &= b\sin{(b^{1-1} t)}
  %\\  &= b\sin{t}
\end{align}
$$

It has been shown $\sin{(bt)} = b\sin{(t)}$, but this does not make sense... surely there is something wrong with the assumption that there is a $c$ such that $c^{m+1} = b^m$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say $c^{m+1}=b^m$ for some specific $m$, that makes sense (but your series calculation is wrong).

What you need for your calculation to work is $c^{m+1}=b^m$ for **every** even value of $m$, that is,
$$c^1=b^0\quad\hbox{and}\quad c^3=b^2\quad\hbox{and}\quad c^5=b^4\quad
  \hbox{and}\ldots\ .$$
The only possible solutions are $b=1,c=1$ and $b=-1,c=1$.  In both of these cases, it is in fact true that $\sin(bt)=b\sin t$.